# Change y-axis scaling midway through the data range via Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphics

Plots showing vertical slices of some field variable in meteorology will often "split" the scaling of the y-axis into two separate regimes, so that both the troposphere and stratosphere can be easily visualized. See the example below. Note that the scaling changes above 100 hPa. I have no idea how to achieve this with `matplotlib`. Any suggestions?

[image]